# React phone number input is causing a webpack error on cypress

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress

When i tried run a cypress test that use a react-phone-number-input a webpack error appears, this error only appears in cypress, my react project don't show this error and works fine, is there a solution in webpack or cypress that can remove this error?

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/react-phone-number-input/style.css 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* CSS variables. */

> :root {
|   --PhoneInputCountrySelect-marginRight: 0.35em;
|   --PhoneInputCountrySelectArrow-width: 0.3em;
 @ ./src/components/InputPhoneNumber/index.js 15:0-44
 @ ./src/components/SignUpForm/index.js
 @ ./src/components/ProductForm/index.js
 @ ./src/tests/ProductForm.spec.js
```

My Webpack config is this

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'public' }
      ]
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader' // inject CSS to page
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run postcss actions
            options: {
              plugins: function () { // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your css loader is choking on the css variable usage. What version are you using?

Comment: "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
"cypress": "^6.2.1",

Comment: Your css-loader is a pretty old version. Try updating it to the latest.

Comment: I update css-loader to the lastest version v5.0.1 and still not working

Comment: What about style loader? Is it also at an old version?

Comment: I had version 1.2.1 and I updated it to the latest version 2.0.0 and it still not working

Comment: Can you show the import used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css-loader doesn’t compile css root parameters.

This answer will help you solve the problem
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/69#issuecomment-108597013